# CSS function in JavaScript does not do border animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, border

perfectly easy to read small sample code ,to demonstrate the problem with the function.

```
 (http://jsfiddle.net/gKfGw/)!


/*for the hovering over any item in the menu*/
$('.navy').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css({"border-bottom " : "2px solid #13B213"}); /*green*/
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).css({"border-bottom " : "2px solid #666666"}); /*grey*/
    }
);
```

line 9 in CSS : the default color .
line 4 in JavaScript  : the color on mouse hover .
line 7 in JavaScript  : the color on mouse moves away.

can you please tell me a way so that i could be able to change the color of the bottom border when i move the mouse over it ?

Comment: Add your code here don't just post external links to code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*for the hovering over any item in the menu*/
$('li.navy').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid #13B213"); /*green*/
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid #666666"); /*grey*/
    }
);
```

Notice syntax of .css method

**EDIT:**

Actually both syntax work, but no space allowed after border-bottom

Comment: Thx alot for your answer , i must have confused the animate function syntax with the CSS syntax.

Comment: Actually, I think your syntax will still work.  It was the space after border-bottom

Comment: Yeah, both syntaxes work, one is faster than the other one though.

Comment: @ Karl-André Gagnon can you please tell me which one is faster than the other ?

Answer (score 0):

This is EASY in pure CSS:

```
li.navy:hover{
 border-bottom-color : #13B213;/*greeen*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKfGw/4/

Comment: yes , but I want to edit all of them when the mouse moves on any of them , css cant do that .